# How to install libsdl2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install libsdl2 on Ubuntu 22.04 using: `apt-get install libsdl2-dev`

but getting following error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Breaks: systemd (< 249.11-0ubuntu3.12) but 249.11-0ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
        Recommends: systemd-hwe-hwdb but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What can I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have dependencies problem, I doubt it's specific to the package you're trying to install. Have you updated your system before trying to install libsdl2-dev ? If not, it may resolve the problem.

Run :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Both systemd-hwe-hwdb and systemd (249.11-0ubuntu3.12) are distributed under jammy-updates so check that the jammy-updates repository line is not commented in /etc/apt/sources.list . A good hint that it's missing is if you don't see a list for the jammy-updates repository when running `apt-get update`.

I don't know what repositories you are using so I won't provide any, but if there's no links to jammy-updates, you can copy the line for the jammy repository and replace jammy with jammy-updates, it should work.

When the dependency problem is resolved you'll be able to install the package with `apt-get install libsdl2-dev`.